# React: Tagging active component in an array with a CSS class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am loading a series of sentences into an array Sentences in React. On my front end I have one "active" sentence and after user form input the next sentence in the loaded array should become "active" with a new CSS class attached to it.

How would I go about doing this? I understand `SentenceList` needs to keep track of the `active_sentence` and the `Sentence` needs to tell `SentenceList` has been updated, and when it does it should set the class "active" to the next sentence sequentially. But I'm not sure how to implement it.

`SentenceList`:

```
var SentenceList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var sentences = [];
    active_sentence = 0;

    //loop through sentences and push each sentence into array
    this.props.sentences.forEach(function(sentence) {

      // increment an index variable here and put an if index === active_sentence statement?

      //grabs @sentences from Rails
      sentences.push(<Sentence key={sentence.id} details={sentence} />)
    });

    return (
      <div>{sentences}</div>
    )
  }
});
```

`Sentence`:

```
var Sentence = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      //
    }
  },

  addBlip: function(e) {
    var blipBody = this.refs.newBlip.getDOMNode().value;
    var sentenceId = this.props.details.id;
    var thisSentenceComponent = this;

    $.ajax({
      url: '/sentences/' + sentenceId + '/blips',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {blip: {body: blipBody}}
    });

    e.preventDefault();
  },

  render: function() {
    //get user input and submit blip and make next sentence "active"
    var phrase = this.props.details.body;
    var phrase_display = phrase.split("*");

    return (
      <div className="blipForm">
        {phrase_display[0]}
        {this.props.details.index}
        <form onSubmit={this.addBlip}>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref="newBlip"
          />
        </form>
        {phrase_display[1]}
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable in state (`activeKey` in this example) to keep track of which sentence key is considered active, then a prop can be passed to `Sentence` telling it whether it is active.  The function `setActiveKey` below can be used to update the active sentence when you load a new sentence :

```
var SentenceList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      activeKey: false
    };
  },
  setActiveKey(newActiveKey){
    this.setState({activeKey: newActiveKey}); 
  },
  render: function() { 
    var sentences = [];
    this.props.sentences.forEach(function(sentence) {
      sentences.push(<Sentence isActive={this.state.activeKey === sentence.id} key={sentence.id} details={sentence} />)
    }.bind(this));
    return (
      <div>{sentences}</div>
    )}
});
```

Then within the render function of `Sentence`, you can the prop `isActive`, and if the value is true, you can render it with the active style:

```
render: function() {  
  var phrase = this.props.details.body
  var phrase_display = phrase.split("*");

  return (
    <div className="blipForm" style={this.props.isActive ? styles.active : styles.inactive}>
      {phrase_display[0]}
      {this.props.details.index}
      <form onSubmit={this.addBlip}>
        <input type="text"
             ref="newBlip" />
      </form>
      {phrase_display[1]}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And you can control your styles in a variable (`styles` here):

```
var styles={
  active:{
    //set active styles here
  },
  inactive:{
    //set inactive styles here
  }
};
```